Skip error while manually installing Intel HD Graphics driver
I am running this in Windows 8.1 PowerShell for installing Intel HD Graphics driver
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
cd "C:\Users\Matheus\Downloads\Drivers\GFX_2A_None_1663644985\Intel-29198_a08_win64_15.45.29.5077\Graphics"
$signature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature igdlh.cat
$store = Get-Item -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher
$store.Open("ReadWrite")
$store.Add($signature.SignerCertificate)
$store.Close()
PnPutil.exe -i -a igdlh64.inf

I get

Microsoft PnP Utility
Processing inf :            igdlh64.inf
Adding the driver package failed : The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likel
y corrupt or the victim of tampering.
Total attempted:              1
Number successfully imported: 0

Note that I have tried the proper Intel installer, but it errors because of Vulkan which does not exist in Windows 8.1 I think:


I was able to install the display audio driver manually though; the graphics one not, because the certificate seems to be broken. I'll try installing DevCon.

It sounds like you are attempting to install a driver that is either not signed, signed by an expired certificate, or otherwise is not hashed properly. Why are you not running the  Intel HD installer?

@Ramhound Included two prints on why the Intel HD installer is not working (it errors at that part).

Instead of a screenshot of an error, can you provide the setup log, for the installation.  This will contain information that can be references in a search. Vulkan is a function of the Intel display drivers not Windows.

@Ramhound I am not able to copy the logs, just the README. Tried Ctrl + C in any item there and nothing

Without the log generated by the installer this diagnose will be nearly impossible.  Is the .cab file you are attempting to use signed by a valid certificate?

I fear you will have to run BCDEDIT /set nointegritychecks OFF in order to install this particular driver. This would decrease system security significantly

I figured out it is in general not possible to install drivers designed for Windows 10 under Windows 8.1 even if skipping the certificates. At best only the Quacomm WLAN driver worked here for the Wi-Fi; I do not have touchpad, brightness adjusting and sound input and output support in my Windows 8.1.
For anyone trying the same (I will never waste my time like this again):
I have installed Windows 10 as a secondary operating system, extracted drivers from it through:
dism /online /export-driver /destination:<full folder path>

Returned to Windows 8.1 and disabled "Driver signature enforcement" by going in Recovery > Advanced Settings > Advanced Startup Options in the Boot menu.
Created an installdrivers.ps1 script as instructed in a blog:
Get-ChildItem "<full folder path>" -Recurse -Filter "*.inf" | 
ForEach-Object { PnPutil.exe -i -a $_.FullName }

Opened PowerShell as administrator and run:
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine

Then run cd to the directory of the .ps1 script and run:
.\installdrivers.ps1

Then clicked yes for each popup.
Then checked for all Windows Updates, installed all updates and restarted the PC. Finally, nothing changed; got Wi-Fi (Quacomm Atheros WLAN) at best through friendly software such as Driver Booster.
